# XOR Swapping output prediction

Tags: c, swap, xor

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(char a[]){

  a[0]^=a[1]^=a[0]^=a[1];

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  char b[10];
  b[0]='h';
  b[1]='j';
  fun(b);
  printf("%c",b[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong with this code. It shall swap the `b[0]` and `b[1]` but it is not swapping.

Comment: Forget the XORs and use a temporary - it's more readable, more reliable and probably more efficient too.

Comment: Funny how people call their functions `fun()` although hey do not do funny things. SCNR :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Undefined behavior** for `a[0]^=a[1]^=a[0]^=a[1];`. Order of evaluation and assignment is not defined.

Comment: +1 C99 6.5/2 : "Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored"

Comment: nice I was going to say 'have you tried it without chaining ^=

Answer (score 3):

The "[The New C Standard. An Economic and Cultural Commentary](http://www.knosof.co.uk/cbook/cbook.html)" book gives two variants of xor-swap at page 1104:

```
Example
1 #define SWAP(x, y) (x=(x ^ y), y=(x ^ y), x=(x ^ y))

2 #define UNDEFINED_SWAP(x, y) (x ^= y ^= x ^= y) 
     /* Requires right to left evaluation. */
```

So, the second variant is not portable and is incorrect.